# How to rewrite create full-text search index for Neo4j 4.4

Tags: neo4j, cypher, fulltext-index

Currently we are using the old method `db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex` to create a full-text search index, but since this is deprecated in 4.4 how to rewrite with `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX`?

```
CALL db.propertyKeys() YIELD propertyKey CALL db.labels() YIELD label WITH 
collect(DISTINCT propertyKey) AS properties, 
collect(DISTINCT label) AS labels 
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex("fullSearchIndex", labels, properties) RETURN labels, properties
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution with [APOC](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/):

```
CALL db.propertyKeys() YIELD propertyKey
CALL db.labels() YIELD label
WITH apoc.text.join(collect(DISTINCT propertyKey), ", n.") as properties, apoc.text.join(collect(DISTINCT label), "|") AS labels
CALL apoc.cypher.runSchema("CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fullSearchIndex FOR (n:" + labels + ") ON EACH [n."+properties+"]", {}) YIELD value RETURN value
```

Remark: `runSchema` needs to be used for schema manipulation operations.